# Prometheus Cost of Repetitive samples

Tags: prometheus

I want to understand how Prometheus compresses data, and what are the cost of repetitive metric. Are they cheap? Does Prometheus has overhead in compressing?

Let's say I have a service that exports metrics. And i want to add another metric called "ok"
This metric will have the value "1", what would be the cost of adding this metric to the TSDB? Would be some constant multiplied by the retension period, or because it's the same some compression will reduce it to nothing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cost of the samples will be extremely small as it'll compress well, the main cost will be the overheard of having a series at all which is about 2KB of RAM for ingestion. For a single time series this is so cheap that it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm interested in how you got to those conclusion, 
could you point out some references?